# bound method DataFrame.toJSON of DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert my dataframe into a json string. I am using pyspark.

This is the code I am using.

```
def produceTrainData (self,csvData): #Array[String] = {

    trainData = csvData.withColumn("therapyClass", lit("REMODULIN"))\
                .withColumn("patientAge", lit(52))\
                .withColumn("patientSex", lit("M"))\
                .withColumn("serviceType", lit("PHARMACY"))\
                .withColumn("npiId", lit("27"))\
                .withColumn("requestID", lit(419568891))\
                .withColumn("requestDateTime", lit("20171909 21:30:55"))\

    selectData = trainData.select("payorId", "patientId","therapyType","therapyClass","ndcNumber","procedureCode","patientAge","patientSex",
                        "placeOfService", "serviceDuration","daysOrUnits","charges", "serviceDate", "serviceType","serviceBranchId",
                        "npiId", "diagnosisCode", "authNbr","requestID", "requestDateTime")

    authNbrFilter = col("authNbr") != "-"        
    filterData = selectData.where(authNbrFilter)#.limit(20)
    print(filterData)

    filterData.show(20,False)

    jsons = filterData.toJSON        

    print(jsons)
```

there are two errors:

1. when I am printing the jsons variable (print(jsons)) it's not returning a rdd like it suppose to do, instead it's returning a:
   bound method DataFrame.toJSON of DataFrame

I am very interesting to know the reason of the error.

2. when I tried to collect the jsons variable is showing the next error:
   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'collect'.

Do you know what it's the reason of this error?

Comment: shouldn't that be: filterData.toJSON() instead of filterData.toJSON ?

Comment: Appreciate you help, you were right. Thank you.